# C convert two digits to one integer

Tags: c

How can I convert a two digits from array to one integer into a new array?

Example: 1245678933658 to [12,45,67,89,33,65,80] add 0 to the last if its an odd.

My try was:

```
new_array[i]=digits[i]*10+digits[i++]*10/10;
```

Comment: If the original digits are ASCII characters, don't forget you have to subtract '0'; that is, '0' - '0' = 0, '1' - '0' = 1, etc.

Comment: Your example is classical UB.

Comment: `i++` increments `i` *after* the original value was passed back. I assume you meant `++i`. But you really should be more explicit in terms of where you increment an index and where you use it so as not to rely on any [sequence point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) assumptions.

Comment: Looks like _base 100_.  `sum = 0; loop: sum = sum*100 + array[i];` with an added condition of _if odd_.  Suggest posting declaration of `dest[]` and `new_array[]` for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it have to be a "one-liner", or would a more readable code also be allowed? Try the following:

```cpp
const char* digits = "12456789336581";
int digitIndex=0;
int numbers[100];
int currentNumberIndex = 0;
int currentNumber = 0;
while (digits[digitIndex]) {
    currentNumber *=10;
    currentNumber += digits[digitIndex] - '0';
    digitIndex++;

    if ( (digitIndex)%2 == 0)  // two digits handled?
    {
        numbers[currentNumberIndex++] = currentNumber;
        currentNumber = 0;
    }
}

// handle the case that last number contained just one digit:
if (digitIndex%2) {
    currentNumber *=10;
    numbers[currentNumberIndex++] = currentNumber;
}

for (int i=0; i < currentNumberIndex; i++)
    printf("number[%d]: %d\n", i, numbers[i]);
```

Comment: Note: `while (isdigit((unsigned char) digits[digitIndex]))` would be a more defensive coding.